# Using variable in select query-Snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am passing a variable(v_A_TYPE) to the select list in below procedure, this variable is having string values. when i pass integer values it is taking but while passing string it is not taking. throwing error like `invalid identifier` .

below is the procedure code look like.

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CDW_PROC.SAMPLE_PROCEDURE(col1 FLOAT, COL2 VARCHAR, COL3 VARCHAR, COL4 VARCHAR, COL5 VARCHAR, COL6 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
try
{

var v_FILTER_ID=0;
var v_A_TYPE=COL2
var v_TYPE=COL3
var v_FILTER_ATTRIBUTE
var v_ORG=COL4;
var v_FILTER_CONDITION,v_FILTER_VALUE,v_FILTER_DESC;
var v_BRAND ='v_BRAND';
var v_F_TIME_CUR = 'v_F_TIME_CUR';
var v_F_TIME_PREV='v_F_TIME_PREV';
var v_F_RANK='v_F_RANK';
var v_F_TIME_BUCKET='v_F_TIME_BUCKET';
var v_CODE='v_CODE';
var v_ID=col1;
var v_TIME_FRAME=COL5;
var v_WK_MTH_FLG=COL6;

var SEL_SQL=snowflake.execute({sqlText: "SELECT ID,TYPE,ORG,SUB_TYPE,FILTER_ID,FILTER_DESC,FILTER_ATTRIBUTE,FILTER_CONDITION,FILTER_VALUE,TIME_FRAME,WK_MTH_FLG FROM CDW_DB.FCT_TABLE  WHERE ID=? AND TYPE =? AND SUB_TYPE =? AND ORG=? AND TIME_FRAME=? AND WK_MTH_FLG =?",binds:[v_ID,v_A_TYPE, v_TYPE, v_ORG, v_TIME_FRAME, v_WK_MTH_FLG]});


while(SEL_SQL.next())
{
var v_ID=SEL_SQL.getColumnValue(1);
var v_A_TYPE=SEL_SQL.getColumnValue(2);
       
v_WORK_SQL = `insert into CDW_DB.TEMP_TABLE1
select DISTINCT  FCT.CUST_ID,
${v_FILTER_ID},
${v_A_TYPE},
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FCT.CUST_ID ORDER BY FCT.DT_SK ASC,FCT.CREATEDDATE ASC) AS RNK
from CDW_VW.FCT_TABLE FCT WHERE CUST_ID <> -1
and CALL_DATE_VOD > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) QUALIFY  RNK=1;`;

var v_WORK_SQL_EXEC=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: v_WORK_SQL});

var VOL2_RESULT=v_WORK_SQL_EXEC.execute();

var RESULT='Success';
return RESULT;
}
  catch(err)
 {
 RESULT="Failed: Code: "+err.code+"\\n State:  "+ err.state;
 RESULT+="\\n  Message:  "+err.message;
 RESULT+="\\n Stack Trace:\\n"+err.StackTraceTxt;
return RESULT;
}
$$
;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put single quotes:

```
v_WORK_SQL = `insert into CDW_DB.TEMP_TABLE1
select DISTINCT  FCT.CUST_ID,
${v_FILTER_ID},
'${v_A_TYPE}',
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FCT.CUST_ID ORDER BY FCT.DT_SK ASC,FCT.CREATEDDATE ASC) AS RNK
from CDW_VW.FCT_TABLE FCT WHERE CUST_ID <> -1
and CALL_DATE_VOD > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) QUALIFY  RNK=1;`;
```